# preg_match_all - doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I want match by this regular expression **\$[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]***

For example:

```
$string = "\$a some text \$b another \$c \$d";
```

Expected return (bold text ist match):

**$a** some text **$b** another **$c $d**

When I run this code

```
$input_lines = "\$a \$b \$c \$d";
preg_match_all("/\$[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]*/", $input_lines, $output_array);
var_dump($output_array);
```

It returns me this:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Expected results should be:

```
array(1
0   =>  array(4
0   =>  $a
1   =>  $b
2   =>  $c
3   =>  $d
)
)
```

I use PHP5.6

I don't know why. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Oh yes it does! So it would be best to approach this from the perspective of, woops what have I done wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = "\$a some text \$b another \$c \$d";
preg_match_all("/\\$\w+/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $a
            [1] => $b
            [2] => $c
            [3] => $d
        )
)
```

In the regex, you must escape the `$` sign and also the `\` itself.
Are both key-characters for regex.

Comment: Because you must escape the $ sign and also the \ itself. Are both key-characters for regex

Comment: Or you could just use single quotes on your variable and regex string

Comment: @user2342558 Would be good to add that sort of thing to your answer, so others can see why you have done what you have done